# zip_longest to filter dataframe and output multiple csv files

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby, series

I have a dataframe like as shown below

```
ID,Region,Supplier,year,output
1,ANZ,AB,2021,1
2,ANZ,ABC,2022,1
3,ANZ,ABC,2022,1
4,ANZ,ABE,2021,0
5,ANZ,ABE,2021,1
6,ANZ,ABQ,2021,1
7,ANZ,ABW,2021,1
8,AUS,ABO,2020,1
9,KOREA,ABR,2019,0

data = pd.read_clipboard(sep=',')
```

My obejctive is to

a) Filter the dataframe by **`year>=2021` and `output==1`**

b) Generate multiple csv files for each unique combination of `region` and `supplier`. For example, data for `ANZ` and `AB` should be stored in seperate file. Similarly, KOREA and ABR data should be stored in seperate file.. This has to be done for each unique combination of region and supplier

So, I tried the below

```
column_name = "region"
col_name = "supplier"
region_values = data[column_name].unique()
supplier_values = data[col_name].unique() 

for i in itertools.zip_longest(region_values,supplier_values,fillvalue="ANZ"):
    data_output = data.query(f"{column_name} == i[0] & Year>=2021 & output == 1 & {col_name} == i[1]")
    output_path = ATTACHMENT_DIR / f"{i}_ge_2021.csv"
    data_output.to_csv(output_path, index=False)
```

However, this results in error as shown below

> KeyError: 'i'
>
> During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
>
> KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call
> last) ~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\computation\scope.py
> in resolve(self, key, is_local)
> 205                 # e.g., df[df > 0]
> --> 206                 return self.temps[key]
> 207             except KeyError as err:
>
> KeyError: 'i'
>
> The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:
>
> UndefinedVariableError                    Traceback (most recent call
> last)
> C:\Users\aksha~1\AppData\Local\Temp/ipykernel_31264/2689222803.py in
>
> 1 for i in itertools.zip_longest(subregion_values,disti_values,fillvalue="ANZ"):
> ----> 2     data_output = data.query(f"{column_name} == i[0] & Year>=2021 & output == 1 & {col_name} == i[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HktOV.png)")

I expect my output to have 5 csv files generated in the folder because there are 5 unique combination of region and supplier that meet filter criteria of year and output

**update - zip_longest - incorrect output**

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `@` for pass variables to `query`, for columns names are correct `f-string`s:

```
#i, j are same like i[0], i[1]
for i, j in itertools.zip_longest(region_values,supplier_values,fillvalue="ANZ"):
    data_output = data.query(f"{column_name} == @i & year>=2021 & output == 1 & {col_name} == @j")
```

Your solution also workign with `@`:

```
for i in itertools.zip_longest(region_values,supplier_values,fillvalue="ANZ"):
    data_output = data.query(f"{column_name} == @i[0] & year>=2021 & output == 1 & {col_name} == @i[1]")
```

Also is possible use f-strings for variables, but need pass `repr` for representation of `i` variables:

```
for i in itertools.zip_longest(region_values,supplier_values,fillvalue="ANZ"):
    data_output = data.query(f"{column_name} == {repr(i[0])} & year>=2021 & output == 1 & {col_name} == {repr(i[1])}")
```

Comment: @TheGreat - I edited answer, for me working unpack `itertools.zip_longest` to `i, j` and then call @i and @j for variables